# How can I access a public variable from an Instance of an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instance, gameobject

I currently have a GameMaster object which I am using to save stats through transitioning scenes. One of the fields that I'm storing is the `playerMaxHealth` value. I am attempting to load this value into the Player object in the `playerStats.MaxHealth` value at the beginning of every scene. At this point my GameMaster instantiation is working perfectly and the values are being saved from scene to scene, but I am having trouble accessing the `playerMaxHealth` value from the newly loaded Player object. I've tried numerous things, including solutions on this site, and I am never able to access this object. I've included the code from my current attempt, in the form of both scripts, as well as the current error message (its changed with every different method I try). What is the correct way of accessing this value and loading it into the Player `playerStats.MaxHealth` value?

GAMEMASTER:

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class GameMaster : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static GameMaster Instance;    

        public static int playerLevel = 1;
        public static int playerExp = 0;
        public static int expTilNextLevel = 1000;
        public static int playerMaxHealth = 100;


        void Awake () {
            if (Instance == null) {
                DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
                Instance = this;
            }
            else if (Instance != this){
                Destroy (gameObject);
            }
        }

        void Update() {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L)){
                AddExp();
            }

            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H)){
                //Player.DamagePlayer(10);
            }
        }

        public static void KillPlayer (Player player) {
            Destroy (player.gameObject);
        }

        public static void KillEnemy (Enemy enemy) {
            Destroy (enemy.gameObject);
            AddExp();
        }

        private static void AddExp () {
            playerExp += 100;
            if (playerExp >= expTilNextLevel) {
                playerLevel++;
                playerExp = playerExp - expTilNextLevel;
                expTilNextLevel = (int)((float)expTilNextLevel * 1.5f);
            } 
            Debug.Log("Player Exp: " + playerExp + "/" + expTilNextLevel + "   Player Lvl: " + playerLevel);
        }

    }
```

PLAYER:

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Player : MonoBehaviour
    {

        [System.Serializable]
            public class PlayerStats {
            public int MaxHealth = 100;
            public int Health = 100;
            public int Exp = 0;
            public int Strength = 1;
        }

        public PlayerStats playerStats = new PlayerStats();


        void Start() {
            GameObject gameMaster = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameMaster") as GameObject;
            playerStats.MaxHealth = gameMaster.playerMaxHealth;
            Debug.Log("Player Max Health: ");
        }


        public void DamagePlayer(int damage){
            playerStats.Health -= damage;
            if (playerStats.Health <= 0) {
                GameMaster.KillPlayer(this);
                Debug.Log ("YOU DIED");
            }
        }

    }
```

Error message:  'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'playerMaxHealth' and no accessible extension method 'playerMaxHealth' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: _and I am never able to access this object_ What happens when you do?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include the error message. Its now been added. It says that GameObject does not contain a definition for playerMaxHealth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `GameMaster` is a component that is attached to the `GameObject`, then `playerMaxHealth` is a property of that component and not the `GameObject`.

What you want to do is get the component itself so that you can access the member variable.

eg:

```
GameMaster gameMasterComponent = gameMaster.GetComponent<GameMaster>();

playerStats.MaxHealth = gameMasterComponent.playerMaxHealth;
```

Alternately, since you are treating `GameMaster` as a singleton, and `playerMaxHealth` is static, either of the following should also work:

```
// as singleton 
playerStats.MaxHealth = GameMaster.Instance.playerMaxHealth;

// as static property
playerStats.MaxHealth = GameMaster.playerMaxHealth;
```

Comment: I've tried your first solution, but I get an error message telling me that `gameMaster` does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @BlakeSimmons to be clear, you're not replacing `GameObject gameMaster = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameMaster") as GameObject;` with my first example, are you? If the component is not a singleton or static, then you need a reference to the `GameObject` that it is attached to.

Comment: Sorry, yes I did replace it. Should I have included it above your addition? In any case, the third solution does work. I could have sworn I had tried this already but I guess I must have done it differently.

Comment: I take it back. It does set the MaxHealth value when the Player loads the first time, but after transitioning to the next scene, I don't believe it is being reloaded. I think this may be a different issue though, because my debug message isn't even printing.

Comment: Nevermind. I believe its because I hadn't properly loaded the character prefab. I'll update once I've tested that.